# pg gem error with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, bundler, pg

I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.2. I install Ruby+RVM using the RailsInstaller, so I am currently on ruby-1.9.3-p194. My application uses Rails 3.2.11.

When I run bundle install, here's the error I see:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/usr/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... yes
checking for PQisthreadsafe()... yes
checking for PQprepare()... yes
checking for PQexecParams()... yes
checking for PQescapeString()... yes
checking for PQescapeStringConn()... yes
checking for PQescapeLiteral()... yes
checking for PQescapeIdentifier()... yes
checking for PQgetCancel()... yes
checking for lo_create()... yes
checking for pg_encoding_to_char()... yes
checking for pg_char_to_encoding()... yes
checking for PQsetClientEncoding()... yes
checking for PQlibVersion()... yes
checking for PQping()... yes
checking for rb_encdb_alias()... yes
checking for rb_enc_alias()... no
checking for PGRES_COPY_BOTH in libpq-fe.h... no
checking for PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE in libpq-fe.h... no
checking for struct pgNotify.extra in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make
compiling pg.c
pg.c: In function ‘Init_pg_ext’:
pg.c:384: error: ‘PQPING_OK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pg.c:384: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
pg.c:384: error: for each function it appears in.)
pg.c:386: error: ‘PQPING_REJECT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pg.c:388: error: ‘PQPING_NO_RESPONSE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
pg.c:390: error: ‘PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [pg.o] Error 1
```

Please note that this is not an issue with pg_config. The responses to similar questions here on StackOverflow all indicate that this binary is missing (or is not found), hence the issue for the error. This seems to be a different problem, as far as I can see.

Any ideas on how I can go about fixing this issue?

Thanks!

Ringo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used homebrew to install pg and that solved my problems:

```
$ brew install postgres
```

Comment: "`brew install pg` says "no formula available". Clarify exactly what you did that "solved your problems".